# Tomcat Application Manager won't authenticate

Tags: tomcat, manager-app

I'm running a local Tomcat 6.0 server. I can get to the main admin page from a browser. I've created a user for the Tomcat Application Manager by configuring tomcat-users.xml like so:

```
<tomcat-users>
      <role rolename="manager-gui" /> 
      <user username="myUsername" password="myPswd" roles="manager-gui" /> 
</tomcat-users>
```

When I type a cmd for TAM e.g. http://localhost:8080/manager/list, it prompts for credentials w/ the Authentication Required dialog. I enter myUsername/myPswd, and the dialog just re-prompts for credentials again.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The roles required to use the Manager application in Tomcat 7 were changed from the single manager role in Tomcat 6 to the following four roles:

- manager-gui - allows access to the HTML GUI and the status pages
- manager-script - allows access to the text interface and the status
- pages manager-jmx - allows access to the JMX proxy and the status
- pages manager-status - allows access to the status pages only

If you are using Tomcat 6 you need to change the role to "manager".

Comment: you saved my day! couldn't figure out until I saw your post about tomcat 6

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like this too, I don't know if its a problem with my version of the manager/tomcat or if I have a newer tomcat then manager version but I've found that I have to use the legacy role 'manager' despite being on 6.0.x.

```
  <role rolename="manager" /> 
  <user username="myUsername" password="myPswd" roles="manager" />
```

Comment: Wow, that did it, despite the Tomcat 6 doc. Tnx!